# looks like conntrack utility is installed but i cannot find it

Tags: linux, iptables, router, conntrack

Ive been told to use the 'conntrack' utility (http://linux.die.net/man/8/conntrack) for some purpose.

now as in the description writen:

```
  conntrack -L
      Dump the connection tracking table in /proc/net/ip_conntrack format
```

so i found the log file in /proc/net/ip_conntrack and it updates at realtime on every ip conntrack, but when i type 'conntrack' i get not found.
its a d-link router with Linux version 2.4.20

how can i find that file to use it if they changed the name or its hidden somewhere

Comment: Which custom firmware are you using?

Comment: its not custom its a pocket router that came build in with busybox(1.00) router firmware is 1.02 - d-link Dir-457U

Comment: I have the open GPL right in front of me but i still cant point on the file location

Comment: What is a GPL, besides the GNU Public License?

Comment: Its the router open source at least thats how d-ink calls it, i can modify compile and the install custom firmware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conntrack` is an utility to see and modify the conntrack tables - but they are unrelated as far as dependencies go. The fact that you have conntrack tables (that's what you're seeing in `/proc`) doesn't imply you must have this utility: the tables are part of Linux itself, you could say, but the utility is just that - an utility - and indeed it's more likely not to be present as it isn't in most default installs, and I would not expect it to be present in a router Linux distribution.

See your distribution docs to find out how to install utilities, but try `/usr/sbin/conntrack` just in case it's installed to `/usr/sbin` and you haven't got the standard root `$PATH` set.

As a last resort look for it in the whole filesystem (you could use locate for faster searching, but I'm guessing your router distro doesn't have it installed):

```
find / -name 'conntrack'
```

Comment: i guess you are right, not exist in /usr/sbin or /usr/bin and also i do not have find or locate installed there :( thank you.

Comment: i just hope they didnt just changed it name like i saw on other files